# GWT Async call always fail

Tags: java, gwt, callback

I have some problems with my gwt project, i use eclipselink and hsqldb as database.

Here is my code:
**Project.java:**

```
package com.example.client;
public class Project implements EntryPoint {

private final EmployeeServiceAsync eService = (EmployeeServiceAsync) GWT.create(EmployeeService.class);

[...] some GWT code


@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

        eService.createemployee(new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Window.alert("Fail!");
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            //nothing
            }
        });
```

but it fail every time with this warning:

```
WARNING: No file found for: /project/employeeService
```

So how i can call this method properly?

**EmployeeService.java**

```
package com.example.client.service;
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("employeeService")
public interface EmployeeService extends RemoteService{

public void createemployee();
}
```

**EmployeeServiceAsync.java**

```
package com.example.client.service;
public interface EmployeeServiceAsync {

void createemployee(AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
}
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl**

```
package com.example.server.ServiceImpl;
public class EmployeeServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements EmployeeService {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void createemployee() {

    javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ronfPU");
    javax.persistence.EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


    try {
 // Create new Employee
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setName("admin");
    e1.setSurname("admin");
    e1.setUsername("admin");
    e1.setPassword("admin");
    em.persist(a1);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
    em.close();
    }   
  }
}
```

Employee class is stored in com.example.shared.entity; I think that persistence.xml and project.gwt.xml are ok, but i'm not sure about **web.xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>employeeServiceImpl</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  com.example.server.ServiceImpl.EmployeeServiceImpl
</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>employeeServiceImpl</servlet-name>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Project.html</welcome-file>
<url-pattern>/com.example.client.Project/employeeService</url-pattern>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

First  should be, if I understand correctly, derives from `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("employeeService")`; 
while `<servlet-class>` derives from the class stored in the server-side wich extends RemoteServiceServlet; `<servlet-mapping>` should be the same of `<servlet-name>`, and here, in `<url-pattern>`, i'm not sure about what i wrote.

How you suggest to run properly this code? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating the code for your client-side service-async stub, it takes the value of the `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` annotation and prefixes it with the `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` (this is explained in [the javadoc for `RemoteServiceRelativePath`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteServiceRelativePath.html)).

`GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` is the "folder" where your `nocache.js` file is located. In a *standard* setup, this depends directly on the name of your module (`project.gwt.xml` and the package you put it in) or a `rename-to` argument you have in it. According to the error message, it's `http://…/project/` in your case (your `nocache.js` is at `project/project.nocache.js`).

You have to adjust the `<url-pattern>` in your web.xml file to match that URL, so it should be `/project/employeeService` in your case.

Put simply: with `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` you configure which URL the client code will call, and with `<url-pattern>` you configure at which URL your service "listens at"; and you have to make them match in order to make them talk to each other.

Comment: if I set `<url-pattern>` as `/project/employeeService` I see a new error in console: `SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void com.example.client.service.EmployeeService.createemployee()' threw an unexpected exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "ronfPU" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl`. Have you any idea what it is? Thanks

Comment: ah, "ronfPU" is `<persistence-unit name="ronfPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">` setted in persistence.xml

Comment: One error at a time. You fixed your "No file found for: /project/employeeService" error, right? Now if you have another issue, feel free to ask another question.